# matplotlib line chart including extra data

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to make a line chart and it keeps starting with year 2000 however, my data starts in 2019. Not sure how to fix it. It worked with a previous dataframe but not with this one.

```
norm.plot(figsize = (16, 9), fontsize = 14)
plt.legend(fontsize = 14)
plt.show()
```

[This is my output chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqlsC.png)

[this is the beginning of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZYli.png)

Comment: You should post a sample of data in the text form that can be easily copied, **not images**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html